# {detail: Unsupported media type "text/plain; charset=utf-8" in request.}

Tags: django, flutter

I am using Flutter and Django and have this error when try to call the backend

Back end error :
{detail: Unsupported media type "text/plain; charset=utf-8" in request.}

Flutter code :

```
Future<void> addAlbum(Album album) async {
print('5');
final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/list-create/');

try {
   print('6');
  final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token dc7e96ed776bc44d013b44fdfe560a616c64646f',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        'title': album.title,
        'cover': album.cover, // => this is an int
        'photos_number': album.photos_number, // => this is an int

      }));
      print('6 ed');
  final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
  print(responseData.toString());

  final newAlbum = Album(
    title: album.title,
    cover: album.cover,
    photos_number: album.photos_number,
  );
  print('6 edddgg');

  _items.add(newAlbum);

  print('6 f');
  notifyListeners();
} catch (error) {
   print('7');
  print(error);
  throw error;
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

Add json content type header.

```
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Token dc7e96ed776bc44d013b44fdfe560a616c64646f',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
```